# ExceptionMessage: "The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.twitter.com'"

Tags: c#, twitter, iis-7, twitterizer

I have used  Twitterizer c# library to post on twitter and my code is working fine on local machine. But when I deploy it in IIS 7 server i'm getting below exception:

```
ExceptionMessage: "The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.twitter.com'"
ExceptionType: "Twitterizer.TwitterizerException"
InnerException: {Message: "An error has occurred.",…}
Message: "An error has occurred."
```

Can anyone plz help me out on this(I'm new to IIS as well as Twitterizer)?

Comment: looks like the firewall (or something else) is blocking the request.

Comment: Install all the features of IIS by going to "Add features". Just give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @murtazaMunshi yes, I'm still getting the same error